# Create SOLR index by parsing "content" via GET (URL)

Tags: solr

is it possible to create a SOLR index by parsing the "content" to index via GET (URL)?
The examples I found allowed this only by reading the content directly from a file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be able to use curl to do that. The request should most probably be something like (untested):-

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update?key1=val1&key2=val2'
```

and so on where key1 and key2 are the fields and val1 and val2 are their corresponding values. Do note though that you will need to send a commit command also to the above url after sending the above request.

You can also look at the following url :-

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

Search for the phrases 'Updating via GET'  and   'Updating a Data Record via curl'

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Solr Data Import Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) - focusing on the [XML/HTTP Datasource](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2BAC8-HTTP_Datasource). If I understand correctly what you are asking this should be able to meets your needs.